# get value from same table according to parrentid

Tags: mysql, sql

this is Product table

```
id |Name |ParentId 
1  | A   | null
2  | B   | 1
3  | C   | 2
4  | D   | 2
5  | E   | 3
```

by using upper table
I would like to try to find a way doing getting back something like this:

```
id |Name |ParentName 
1  | A   | null
2  | B   | A
3  | C   | B
4  | D   | B
5  | E   | C
```

how can i achive that?

Comment: hoping its simple you are after, recursive parents gets a little more complicated.

Comment: @danblack he is only after the immediate parent. Agreed that it would need CTEs (available only in MySQL 8.0+) if he is looking to get the oldest parent.

Answer (score 1):

Use self join

```
select a.id,
       a.Name,
       b.Name as parentname
from product a 
left join product b 
  on a.id=b.parentid
```

Comment: added alias on id otherwise code will return ambiguous column error.

Answer (score 1):

use self join

```
  select t1.*,t2.Name as ParentName
  from Product_table t1 left join Product_table t2 on t1.id=t2.parentid
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more useful,

with List

as

(

select id,Name

```
     ,(select pr.Name from Product  pr where pr.id=pd.id) as ParentName from Product pd
```

)

select * from List

Answer (score 0):

please try using join:

select t1.id,
       t1.Name,
       t2. Name as parentname
from product a 
left join product b 
  on t1.id=t2.parentid

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following code.

```
select table1.*,table2.Name as ParentName
  from Product_table table1 left join Product_table table2 on table1.id=table2.parentid
```